# Merge Tag [wix-react-native-navigation] into [react-native-navigation]

Tags: support, retag-request

The tags [wix-react-native-navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wix-react-native-navigation) and [react-native-navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-native-navigation) both refer to the same library.  It is created by Wix but is distributed [on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-navigation) as just `react-native-navigation`.

This should be an uncontroversial merge as they are clearly the same, but there are a decent amount of questions.  Can mods just batch re-assign all?

---

Tag [wix-react-native-navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wix-react-native-navigation)

253 Questions

Usage Guidelines:

> Questions about Wix's React Native Navigation package (react-native-navigation on npm).

No wiki

---

Tag [react-native-navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-native-navigation)

1,420 Questions

Usage Guidelines:

> Use this tag for questions related to the React Native Navigation library that provides a complete native navigation solution for React Native apps.

Wiki:

> React Native Navigation provides 100% native platform navigation on both iOS and Android for React Native apps.
>
> For more info see github project
>
> https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation